# Matched results in nested foreach loop - PHP

Tags: php

I am querying two sets of data the first contains a full list of address books, the second contains only those that a user is subscribed to. I want to present the full list and just highlight the ones the user's subscribed to. My code so far returns the full list of address books as well as the users address books (in red) but displays duplicates. Can anyone help remove the duplicates?

```
<?php 

    foreach($ch2_response as $ub){
            if($ub['visibility'] == 'Public' ){
                echo $ub['name'] . '<br>';
            }
        foreach($ch1_response as $ab){
           if($ab['visibility'] == 'Public' && $ab['name'] == $ub['name'] ){
                echo '<p style="color:red;">' . $ab['name'] . '</p>';

            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code would go something like this (included example values)

```
<?php

$ch1_response = [
    ["name" => "Book 1", "visibility" => "Public"],
];

$ch2_response = [
    ["name" => "Book 1", "visibility" => "Public"],
    ["name" => "Book 2", "visibility" => "Public"],
    ["name" => "Book 3", "visibility" => "Private"],
];

$userBooks = [];

foreach ($ch1_response as $ub) {
    if ($ub['visibility'] == "Public") {
        $userBooks[] = $ub['name'];
    }
}

usort($ch2_response, function ($a, $b) {
    return (strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']));
});

foreach ($ch2_response as $ab) {
    if ($ab['visibility'] == "Public") {
        if (in_array($ab['name'], $userBooks)) {
            echo '<p style="color:red;">' . $ab['name'] . '</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p>' . $ab['name'] . '</p>';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

First you save all user books names that are Public in one array `$userBooks`. Then we sort `$ch2_response` using `usort` - we compare book names with `strcmp`. Then you loop through all books and check if current book `$ab['name']` exists in `$userBooks` array. If yes, echo book name in color red, otherwise, just echo it without color.

Comment: Thanks so much! this is exactly what I've been trying to do! IS there anyway of ordering the outputs alphabetically?!

Comment: Sure, give me a sec

Comment: you hero! believe it or not that's been bothering me for hours! Thanks!

Comment: No problem dude :) Good luck!

Comment: The first loop in this answer could be replaced with `array_filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can first compare both the arrays and get the unique values in new array and print values using that new array.

```
$new_array = array_unique( array_merge($ch2_response, $ch1_response) );

print_r($new_array);
```

I hope this will help you!